# Не генерируется файл R.java при импорте и создании новых проектов

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, eclipse

Всем привет.

Переустановил ОС на компе, установил eclipse + adt + sdk, однако при импорте старых и создании новых проектов не генерируется R.java и во всех файлах java кучи ошибок, при этом консоль выдает следующее:

> <code> [2015-01-12 19:32:54 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values\styles.xml:7:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.  [2015-01-12
> 19:32:54 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> [2015-01-12 19:32:54 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.  [2015-01-12
> 19:32:54 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> [2015-01-12 19:32:54 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
> [2015-01-12 19:32:54 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> [2015-01-12 19:32:55 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values\styles.xml:7:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.  [2015-01-12
> 19:32:55 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> [2015-01-12 19:32:55 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.  [2015-01-12
> 19:32:55 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> [2015-01-12 19:32:55 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
> [2015-01-12 19:32:55 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> [2015-01-12 19:35:38 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values\styles.xml:7:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.  [2015-01-12
> 19:35:38 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> [2015-01-12 19:35:38 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.  [2015-01-12
> 19:35:38 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> [2015-01-12 19:35:38 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]
> C:\Users\Андрей\workspace\Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8:
> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
> [2015-01-12 19:35:38 -
> Speak_1.1_PushandSearchMenu]  </code>

В чем может быть проблема?

Помимо этого, в файле styles.xml ошибка.

```
<code> <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> 
    <!-- 
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in 
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to 
        backward-compatibility can go here. 
    --> 
</style> </code>
```

Ошибка:

> error: Error retrieving parent for
> item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: @iandryxa5, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` - это не причина, а следствие. Тема `Appcompat` находится в одной из `support library` (вроде в v7). Вот ее и нужно подключить.

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: @iandryxa5
берете сообщение об ошибке, и вставляете в гугл. И получается вот что:    
https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=No+resource+found+that+matches+the+given+name+%27Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar%27&oq=No+resource+found+that+matches+the+given+name+%27Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar%27&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i64.776j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: А вообще - Эклипс - это уже прошлый век. Переходите на IDEA, или - еще лучше, Android Studio